# tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: never being called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`, named `tblParentComments` in a `UIView`, of class `CBox`.

I have definitely **set my view as the datasource and delegate of my table view**, and **my view does implement those protocols**. The method **`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` does get called** and returns a non-zero value. But the function `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is **never called.**

I noticed that if I put the method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in comments, Xcode does NOT stop compiling with an error like "`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is required" -- the app just runs and show a empty table.

I don't understand. Any ideas? This is the code for my view:

Interface CBox.h

```
@interface CBox : UIView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

And in the implementation file:

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {        
        tblParentComments = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        tblParentComments.delegate = self;
        tblParentComments.dataSource = self;
        //tblParentComments.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        tblParentComments.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tblParentComments.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        tblParentComments.bounces = NO;
        [self addSubview:tblParentComments];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate + UITableViewDatasource

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"num of rows = %d", parentComents.count);
    return 1;  // I set a non-zero value for test
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 .... // I set a breakpoint here, never been called here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your rapide reply! I modified the original post.

Comment: Is this view created in an xib, or through code? Where are the `delegate` and `datasource` connections made? In Interface Builder?

Comment: @W'rkncacnter: it is created int the code, cf 'initWithFrame'. tblParentComments.delegate = self;
        tblParentComments.dataSource = self;

Comment: But where is the view itself created?

Comment: In a viewController, I created this view and added it to self.view and after the reload of datas, I called "[tblParentComments reloadData];",

Comment: You're not adding the table view to the view `[self addSubview:tblParentComments]`; do you also have a table view (and maybe a CBox) in an xib?

Comment: I added it in to the view of the viewcontroller.    All of the views and viewControllers are writed in code, I didn't use IB in this project.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "You're not adding the table view to the view [self addSubview:tblParentComments];" --- [self addSubview:tblParentComments] do add the tableview in this view.

Comment: I don't understand why  "numberOfRowsInSection" is called corectly while "cellForRowAtIndexPath" is never called. These two are functions in uitableviewdatasource protocol.  And I don't understand neither why xcode didn't stop with the exception "cellForRowAtIndexPath is required" when I commented "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method.  That's so weird

Comment: Oh! Yes, you do add it. Somehow I completely missed that, sorry.

Comment: if you comment out `numberOfRowsInSection` does it give you an error?

Comment: Yes. The error message is "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CBox tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a3bf10'"  --- but It's weird too. Cause i tried with another view(with table) and i got "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'" when comment "tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath" function.

Comment: wait, when you comment out `numberOfRowsInSection` you shouldn't see `-[CBox tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a3bf10` because you already commented it out!

Comment: @iBlue: That's right! Good point! But I don't understand why. My view is a Subview of UIView. And it stopped juste after [self addSubview:tblParentComments];

Comment: yeah it's kinda weird. If you manually call `[tblParentComments reloadData];` after you add it does both methods get called?

Comment: no, only numberOfRowsInSection is called

Comment: Wait, it starts to be called! And I don't know why! I've deleted the 2 CBox(.h/.m) and recreated these two files, and now the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" is called....

Comment: I still got this problem, but I think I understand better: if I put a view in a viewcontroller, both of them implement uitableviewdatasource, that will cause this problem.

Comment: You shouldn't give a UIView a view controller behavior. The delegate for a UITableView should be a view controller.

Comment: `code`@interface CBox : UIView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`code` Why are you making your VIEW the datasource and delegate instead of making your VIEW CONTROLLER the datasource and delegate?

Answer (score 0):

YES..i have the same problem... and I just found out the solution.

In my class i use different `inits` with different parameters.

In my `-(void)viewDidLoad` i use to `alloc` the table view with `CGRectZero`, and ONLY in this case IF u DONT set up the FRAME of the UITableView then:

- the `numberOfRowsInSection` will BE CALLED
- the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will NEVER BE CALL

I just set up my **UITableView frame** and it's works.

Answer (score 0):

As I read above comments I can figure out couple of things:

You probably have messed up a bit structure of your code. You should always conform to  protocols in your view controller - ! not view. Alternatively, what I like to do (as it gives me better control over my code and it keeps things clean), separate protocols out of view controller - means create new object (model object) that will handle everything what table requires and it will conforms to table delegate and datasource.

If you organise your code wisely, you should avoid situation you described.

Also I believe you may have 2 objects conforming to table protocols, and thats where the things get ugly.